# Android: NullPointerException despite @NonNull

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-annotations, non-nullable

I'm using annotations to ensure that parameter will be not null, assuming this would cause compiler check.

```
public @Nullable ApplicationAccount accountForKey(@NonNull String key) {

    return accounts.get(key);
}
```

However, by running this code I get NullPointerException exactly on this line

```
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get (ConcurrentHashMap.java:883)
```

What is the point of annotations then?

Even more obscuring, if I write additional check like this

```
return key!=null?accounts.get(key):null;
```

Android Studio warns me that the check is useless!

Update: full call stack:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:883)
       at co.getcontrol.services.MerchantCenter.accountForKey(MerchantCenter.java:72)
       at co.getcontrol.model.customers.CustomersAggregator.loadCustomerDetails(CustomersAggregator.java:91)
       at co.getcontrol.model.customers.CustomerDetailsPresenter.callData(CustomerDetailsPresenter.java:39)
       at co.getcontrol.reskin.ui.customers.CustomerDetailsViewFragment.onCreateView(CustomerDetailsViewFragment.java:152)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602)
       at co.getcontrol.ui.ControlActivity.onStart(ControlActivity.java:13)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1174)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5353)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2352)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Compile time and runtime are different things... That @NonNull will not magically prevent a null value, as you just saw... And this is why I don't really like these annotations.

Comment: Hmm, for me it eliminates the whole sense of using annotations then. Without annotation I now I have to care about pointer check. If I write @NonNull then I automatically delegate this duty to someone (compiler). I expect then at least that code which *uses* this method must produce compile error / warning when it does not check for null.

Comment: There are useful annotations. This one is useless. And yep, you have to check your references (no pointers in Java!)...
And you can't delegate this at compile time! Can't. Not possible. Just think of this: You write the best JSON lib in the world, compile it, release it, and someone else calls it with a big fat null. How could the compiler catch that?

Comment: `If I write @NonNull then I automatically delegate this duty to someone (compiler).` **NO**. If you write @NonNull then you tell someone (Lint) that *you are sure that* there will be no Null value at that point and to stop bothering you that you might get a NullPointerException. But this doesn't prevent a NullPointerException from happening.

Comment: `@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` this annotation happened to throw me an error ;) But never used jetbrains things in production code. 
I'm getting 
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'test' of ideone/App.doSth must not be null`
But then again, it might be only in IntelliJ? Not sure how this works ;)

Comment: actually you are missing the purpose of annotation according to java documentation "Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate."

Comment: don't confused it with frameworks which checks these annotations and does operation consider them kind of wrapper.

Answer (score 7):

Annotations create a *contract*. `@NonNull` says that this method does not accept `null` and passing it may crash the program (which is exactly what happened). Android Studio will warn about any uses of this method where it can deduce that `null` may be passed. But it won't prevent passing a `null`.

Very similar contract is parameter to `[]` for an array which cannot be outside of its bounds (e.g. smaller than 0) but that still won't prevent a developer to pass a value outside of the bounds.

The check for `null` is marked as superfluous because by the contract, there should never be `null`. If you add the check, the method will now know how to handle `null` and therefore should not be marked as `@NonNull`.

Answer (score 1):

If you annotate `@NonNull` you declare, that the input will not be `null`. It won't prevent dumb developer from passing a null there.

I would consider adding `guava` checkNonNull instead:

```
public @Nullable ApplicationAccount accountForKey(@NonNull String key) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(key, "Illegal Argument passed: key is Null.");
    return accounts.get(key);
}
```

This will prevent you successfully from passing `null` to the `accounts#get` method.

In your case it looks like your `accounts` is `null`. Investigate that!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Lombok library](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html) with [Android Studio plugin](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin) to achieve support of both: warnings and runtime exception at start of a method just with annotating parameter with `@NonNull` lombok annotation.

It will look like

```
import lombok.NonNull;

public class NonNullExample extends Something {
    private String name;

    public NonNullExample(@NonNull Person person) {
        super("Hello");
        this.name = person.getName();
    }
}
```

Compared with box-java implementation:

```
public class NonNullExample extends Something {
   private String name;

    public NonNullExample(@NonNull Person person) {
        super("Hello");
        if (person == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("person");
        }
        this.name = person.getName();
    }
}
```